# Getting error on installing a plugin in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Getting fatal error when installing a woocommerce theme in wordpress. The error is:

> Fatal error:Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded...

Comment: Open your php.ini of your wordpress site. Change max_execution_time = 30; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds. Replace 30 with around 180 or something, may fix your issue.

Comment: please try to search by your own first, then post your question here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May your plugin's loop endless. If it is not, you could extend the maximum execution time like this:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

Or,

At the top of the file set the timeout:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Or,

I had the same problem and solved it by changing the value for the param max_execution_time in php.ini, like this:

```
max_execution_time = 360      ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds (I CHANGED THIS VALUE)
max_input_time = 120          ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
;max_input_nesting_level = 64 ; Maximum input variable nesting level
memory_limit = 128M           ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB by default)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
search for php.ini file in your localhost at look for the phrase "max_execution_time = 30" and change to 600 . the "30" is for 30 seconds to timeout.

Restart your server and then check.

Hope this helps..

Comment: You're suggesting increasing the timeout by a factor of 20(!)? If that is a genuine fix, there's some really bad software somewhere.